# Should we use content Projection or just call the child component 'normally'?

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

In angular we can call component from another component on two ways.

The first way is content projection.

**APP COMPONENT HTML**

```
<app-parent>
   <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>
```

**PARENT COMPONENT HTML**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

The second way is just calling the child component in the parent itself.

**APP COMPONENT HTML**

```
<app-parent>
</app-parent>
```

**PARENT COMPONENT HTML**

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

I wonder - what are the differences in this approaches - pros and cons.

I don't know what i shold use and WHEN

Comment: i will suggest  you that if you want to understand this concept see this video https://youtu.be/b71prZA8sQ0 hope it will work for you

Comment: I undestand the concepts. but i don't know what should i use in which case. What are pros and cons

Comment: when you have dynamic component and you want to render it than you need to use ng-content

Comment: if i say you want to render some content within your element child without ng-content it will not work 
 <app-child><h1>heading></h1></app-child>

Comment: when you use ng-content in your component it will show that content inside of your component with the class selector

Comment: have you got any idea what am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is which component control the child component and coupling between components :

With projection, the AppComponent is responsible for the ParentComponent's content and ChildComponent's inputs/outputs while for the other way, the ParentComponent is responsible for everything. With the second way, for the AppComponent, the ParentComponent can be viewed as a black box.

The best way is, most of the time, the second way as it lessens coupling between components thus decrease your component's complexity.

Content projection is used when you realy need to customise contents inside another component (ex: a cell in a table or a title of a modal).